# Using case-when for complex query under several condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I have the data shown below:

```
    ID_LIFTING | ITEM | DATE
    ---------------------
    1101       | 6    | 2020-02-01
    1101       | 6    | 2020-02-02
    1101       | 6    | 2020-02-03
    1101       | 7    | 2020-02-01
    1101       | 7    | 2020-02-02
    1101       | 7    | 2020-02-03
    1102       | 6    | 2020-02-04
    1102       | 6    | 2020-02-04
    1102       | 7    | 2020-02-04
    1102       | 7    | 2020-02-04
```

**What I want is**, under similar **ID_DATA** and **ITEM**, there will be one column showing concatenated **date range** as string '**MIN(date) - MAX(date)**'. But if under similar **ID_DATA** the date is similar, it will only show the **DATE** as is without range.

Note that there might be more than 2 rows of **DATE** for a single **ID_DATA**. I'm hoping to use case-when.

**Following expected result**:

```
    ID_LIFTING | ITEM | DATE
    ---------------------
    1101       | 6    | 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03
    1101       | 7    | 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03
    1102       | 6    | 2020-02-04
    1102       | 7    | 2020-02-04
```

Below is the query I've made. My query is still incorrect, I'm confused where to put the correct query for my above expected result :( (it's for **ALD_DATE**). Note that I have many joins below to get the data I need as shown above. **ID_LIFTING** is there after table parameter **D**.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ...
            )
        ,ALD_DATE = (SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(DATE) = MAX(DATE) THEN CAST(MIN(DATE) AS CHAR)
            ELSE CONCAT(MIN(DATE), ' - ', MAX(DATE)) 
       END AS DATE
FROM data
GROUP BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM
ORDER BY ID_LIFTING),

    FROM MYTABLE A
    LEFT JOIN ...;
```

Comment: `Group by` belongs after `where`

Comment: @shawnt00 Ive been wondering about this logic. Thanks that really help me!

Comment: @DaleK yes I do aware. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to check whether the `MIN` and `MAX` values of `DATE` are the same. If not, output a range, otherwise output a single value:

```
SELECT ID_LIFTING, ITEM,
       CASE WHEN MIN(DATE) = MAX(DATE) THEN CAST(MIN(DATE) AS CHAR)
            ELSE CONCAT(MIN(DATE), ' - ', MAX(DATE)) 
       END AS DATE
FROM data
GROUP BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM
ORDER BY ID_LIFTING
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
ID_LIFTING  ITEM    DATE
1101        6       2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03
1101        7       2020-02-01 - 2020-02-03
1102        6       2020-02-04
1102        7       2020-02-04
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/175942/3)

In terms of incorporating this into your query, you'll need to use window functions e.g.

```
ALD_DATE = CASE WHEN MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM) = MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM) THEN CAST(MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM) AS CHAR) 
                ELSE CONCAT(MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM), ' - ', MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM)) 
           END
```

Comment: Csn you tell me how to select ID_LIFTING and ITEM without showing in the main select? Because i dont want both columns to be shown in my table view.. i only need it for generating the column ALD_DATE in my overall query as above. So im confused how to properly put your query into mine. Please help :)

Comment: You don't have to include `ID_LIFTING` and `ITEM` in the select e.g. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/175942/4

Comment: Then should I put it like this as above? Please help check :D

Comment: Please help  check if I put your code in the right way in my query above (I have edited for `ALD_DATE`) :D

Comment: @Jov it's really hard to debug your query without access to all the tables. But I think you should go back to the original, and try `ALD_DATE = CASE WHEN MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM) = MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM) THEN CAST(MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM) AS CHAR)  ELSE CONCAT(MIN(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM), ' - ', MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_LIFTING, ITEM)) 
       END`. You will probably need to qualify `ID_LIFTING` as `C.ID_LIFTING` also you probably need to qualify `DATE` but I'm not sure which table that comes from

Comment: Ah Ive tried that also. Both are now working correctly! Thanks a lot Nick :D

Comment: @Jov so the code in my last comment worked? if so I'll add it to the answer so others can find it.